# UTM parameters are missing in GA4

Tags: http, url, google-analytics-4, utm-tracking

My app sends push notification with this kind of URL:

```
mywebapp.com/#postId?utm_source=push
```

That worked very fine at UA, but at GA4 - source parameter is missing.

Is there a way to get it working?

I have idea to parse URL with js and send it as event in case if will get no answers here

---

**Update**

I tried to update my URL in this way, but it didn't work:

```
mywebapp.com/?utm_source=push#postId
```

**Update 2**

Tried to add also medium parameter, didn't work either

```
mywebapp.com/?utm_source=myAppname&utm_medium=push#postId
```

**Update 3**

Finally it started to work. I don't know exactly why, because few days after I did all changes from above - it wasn't working. Suddenly it works, maybe it takes some time to get this data. Not sure how it was fixed

Comment: thnak you @Quentin, I updated URL as you described in this topic. But in real-time report, I didn't found "push" source. Will deploy it to prod and see if that works, but I have doubts that this is the problem root.